# Some contents of an included file is not loading

Tags: php, include, require-once

I am trying to load contents of a file (myfile.php) into another (index.php) using the include_once() php api. But it is not loading the contents.

```
// contents inside index page
if(include_once('myfile.php')){
    echo D; // this is working
    echo $b; // this is not working
} else {
    echo "unable to include the file";
}   

// contents inside myfile.php
define('D', '123');
$b = "abcd";
```

Comment: Does the `include_once`-call reside inside a function?

Comment: paste myFile.php maybe $b is local var

Comment: Ensure that all code (in `index.php` as well as in `myfile.php`) is wrapped properly in `<?php ?>`-tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be not including it correctly.

You can find this [in the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

```
<?php
// won't work, evaluated as include(('vars.php') == 'OK'), i.e. include('')
if (include('vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}

// works
if ((include 'vars.php') == 'OK') {
    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: I have to wait 5minutes :)

Comment: :) Yeah, I forgot I was so fast answering :P

Answer (score 0):

Include_once does not return true on success, as stated in the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).

You need to use if ((include 'myfile.php') == 'OK') {....}